# Ubuntu 12.10 triple monitors... so close!

Tags: nvidia, 12.10, ati, xorg, multiple-monitors

I'm trying to set up 3 monitors using an ATI Radeon HD 5450 and an NVidia 9600 GSO. I know mixing manufacturers is not desirable, but these were the cards I had laying around. After a few days of tweaking, I finally got all three monitors to at least power on at the same time. I am using the free 'radeon' and 'nouveau' drivers. I think I am very close to getting my desktop working, but I just can't make it right. Preferably, all 3 monitors will each have a launcher and I will be able to move windows between them. I will not be upset if this is not possible, but I just want all 3 on and working. With my current config, my left monitor, powered by the ATI card, is running X just fine. The middle and right monitor both have black screens. I can move my mouse to the middle monitor, and move it around the black screen. The right monitor is mirroring everything on the middle monitor.

Here is my xorg.conf:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
Identifier     "My X Server"
Screen          "LeftScreen" 0 0    
    Screen          "CenterScreen" RightOf "LeftScreen"
    Screen          "RightScreen" RightOf "CenterScreen"    
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
  Option        "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection

Section "Module"
Load  "dbe"
Load  "extmod"
Load  "record"
Load  "glx"
Load    "dri"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier   "LeftMonitor"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier   "CenterMonitor"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier   "RightMonitor"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier  "ATIL"
Driver      "radeon"
#Option     "ZaphodHeads" "DVI-0"
BusID       "PCI:02:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier  "NVIDIAM"
Driver      "nouveau"
#Option     "ZaphodHeads" "DVI-0"
BusID       "PCI:01:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier  "NVIDIAR"
Driver      "nouveau"
#Option     "ZaphodHeads" "DVI-1"
BusID       "PCI:01:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "LeftScreen"
Device     "ATIL"
Monitor    "LeftMonitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "CenterScreen"
Device     "NVIDIAM"
Monitor    "CenterMonitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "RightScreen"
Device     "NVIDIAR"
Monitor    "RightMonitor"
EndSection
```

Has anyone been able to accomplish 3 monitors with nvidia and ati together?

Answer (score 2):

I could do it. I have an onboard ATI card (HD 3200) and a Nvidia PCI-E card (8600GT). I output two monitors from the Nvidia card (DVI->VGA) and one from the onboard.

The performance is not so good. Sometimes I had crashes when (accidentaly) moving videos from one of the Nvidia screens to the ATI one. Also, glxgears doesn't output anything in the ATI monitor. But for the basic standard desktop stuff it works great.

Here's my xorg.conf file, I hope it's useful for you.

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 1360 0
    Screen      1  "Screen2" LeftOf "Screen0"
    Screen      2  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung SyncMaster"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 61.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Philips"
    HorizSync       14.0 - 70.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 85.0
    Option         "DPMS"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor2"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "LG Flatron L177WS"
    HorizSync       31.5 - 50.0
    VertRefresh     40.0 - 90.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 8600 GT"
    BusID          "PCI:02:00:00"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 8600 GT"
    BusID          "PCI:02:00:00"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    Driver         "radeon"
    VendorName     "ATI"
    BoardName      "ATI Radeon HD3200"
    BusID          "PCI:01:05:00"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "CRT-1: 1360x768_60 +0+0; CRT-1: 1360x768 +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "CRT-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen2"
    Device         "Device2"
    Monitor        "Monitor2"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Modes       "1280x640"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
    Option         "Composite" "Disable"
EndSection
```

Comment: Appreciate the reply. I ended up ditching the ATI card for now... gonna snag TWO new nvidia cards when the holiday deals come out... my mobo can't do SLI but I'm drooling for 3 monitors with my new home office setup.